# How can i create a vector of the form?

Tags: matlab, vector

How can i create this vector in Matlab? Please I need your help.

```
Vector = [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 ... 49 49 0 0 50 50 50 50]; %the vector
```

Comment: Why do you need such a complicated vector. Can you not simplify your problem?

Comment: You first need to know the logic behind the vector construction before programming it. If it is just an error on the execution, you can remove the `...` that acts as a comment.

Comment: The ´...´ means continuity

Comment: Is there some logic in this vector? Can you expand it more? What values should be between '3,' and ',50' ? This vector should have two dimensions or one ?

Comment: The vector is just 1D

Comment: What are the input data that define this vector? Does it really end with nonzero values, rather than with two zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two lines

```
v = reshape([repmat((1:50)',1,5) zeros(50,2)]',1,[]);
v(end-1:end) = []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
B = 1:50;
C = repelem(B, 7)';
D = 0;
for j = 1:size(C)
    D = D +1
    if (mod(D, 7) == 0 || mod(D, 7)==6)
        C(j) = 0;
    end
end
```